# Database schema for storing IIS logs

Tags: sql-server, database, iis, database-design, database-schema

I have been trying to come up with a database schema to store IIS Log file information to no success. Our logs currently log,

- Date
- Time
- Client Username
- Client IP
- Client User Agent
- Server IP
- Server sitename
- Status
- Sub status
- win-32-status
- Request method type
- URI-Stem
- URI-query
- Port

What is a good database design to allow me to parse the log files and insert them into a SQL Server database for later querying? I would like to insert it into more than one giant table to help keep the size of the database from growing to fast.

Comment: With this little information: just put it in one table? Please be more specific about your needs!

Comment: Edited question. It doesn't have to be in one table, actually would be preferred not to be :)

Comment: every column besides date and time and those that are already a code (eg Status) could be in a lookup table.

Comment: You fail to specify the one thing that actually matters: how are you query this data? If you're not going to query it, don't store it. If you are going to query it, then do specify what queries you're going to run because that will be the main driver for your design.

Comment: @Hogan so every column be its own table? Then just select the ID's from those tables or Insert a new record then join them to the date and time?

Comment: @michael_clarke I will write an answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a lookup table for the columns that are strings:

```
Client Username
Client IP
Client User Agent
Server IP
Server sitename
Request method type
URI-Stem
URI-query
```

I would setup each of these lookup tables the same.  So for example for clientusername

```
ClientUsername
ID - int unique
VALUE - VARCHAR(100)
```

Then when you process a row you take the username value and see if it is in ClientUsername table if so you add the row with that ID number in the Client Username column.  If not you add the new username to the lookup table and take the new ID and use that.

Repeat for each column you want to have referencing a lookup table.

When selecting from the table you just join to the lookup table to get the value column.

Comment: Ok. As for the statuses what would you do for that? Keep them out of a lookup table?

Comment: @michael_clarke - They are integers... there is no gain in storing an integer to lookup a integer... just store the original integer.  For some of them you can gain a few bytes by using small int

Comment: Ok I'll give this a try and report back the findings. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: @michael_clarke - have fun